# Why this hotkey combination: "Super+V" didn't work?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm fairly a newbie in Ubuntu. (The first day...)

I want to set my own hotkey, but totally failed.

Here is what I've done:

Set my own hotkey:

[image]

But if I press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, it'll be like this:

[image]

At first, I thought the command was wrong, so I tested in terminal:

[image]

It can be launched successfully!

[image]

So, any steps went wrong? Why this hotkey combination didn't work?

Environment: Wubi (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by default in Unity <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> opens the Dash Video Lens:

[image]

And until now there is no way to change this behavior using the default system Keyboard Settings, or applicationss like [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/), [dconf Editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor/), a.o.

So, you probably have to choose another key combination.

Comment: Old post, but your comment is for Unity, NOT Ubuntu. In Ubuntu, the "Super + V" hotkey combo is set to open the calendar/notification dropdown from the top. But that still affects his hotkey setup the same.